# Difference between urllib2 vs requests

Tags: xml, python-2.7, python-requests, urllib2

I'm creating an API, to communicate with another server, in Python 2.7.

My request is in XML format, therefor I add the header with the content-type = application/xml.

Using urllib2:

```
request_xml = <some xml thing>
request = urllib2.Request(self.query_url, request_xml)
request.add_header('Content-Type', 'application/xml'
response_xml = urllib2.urlopen(request).read())
```

Using requests:

```
request_xml = <some xml thing>
headers = {'Content-Type': 'application/xml'}
response_xml = requests.get(self.query_url, data=request_xml, headers=headers).text
```

With requests I get the same result every time i try to communicate with the other server. With urllib2, for the same request, i get a different, and correct, result.

Why this difference?

Thank you.

Comment: Can you share your results?  This doesn't give us much to go on.

Comment: Well... solved my problem, and feel a little dumb.
Apparently urllib2, with data parameter, defaults to a POST request.
So changing to requests.post solves the problem.